# Maximize a box using jquery

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css

when i click on  one panel link "hello" or "Hi", then that panel must be maximized and only that panel must be shown in page, again when i click it back it need to go for its original position, same for other panel, i tried implementing but some where i went out off,when i click on hello link it can be maximized but another panel also can be viewed in page.

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/Soni/tRen6/1/



<script>
$(function() {
    $("#container").sortable({
        handle: 'h1',
        scroll: false,
        revert: true,
        tolerance: 'touch'
    });
$(".button").toggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#0000",
            width: 1000,
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            width: 100,

        }, 500);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a elegant way, but it works

```
$(function() {
$("#container").sortable({
    handle: 'h1',
    scroll: false,
    revert: true,
    tolerance: 'touch'
});

$(".button").toggle(function() {
    $(this).parent().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#0000",
        width: 500,
    }, 500);
    $(".button").fadeOut();
    $(this).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        width: 100,
    }, 500);
    $(".button").fadeIn();
    $(this).fadeIn();

});

});
```

See if it`s resolve.

You can also see [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Or maybe create a class to each elemente.

or try to count with eq(). But I don`t know where you are going to use.

Comment: No,This is not what i am figuring out, when i click on one panel then it need to maxmize and make other panels to hide and when i click on same panel button then it need come back to orginal position

Comment: Let's see. 1) opened painels. 2) click 'hello' and 'hi' is gone(like you can click in it anymore). 3) if click again in 'hello'> Hello back but 'hi' back or not?

maybe (just maybe) you are looking for somethint like [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)?

Comment: No, Not That, Some thing like window browser button on top left, I had 2 boxes i a page, at top left there will be a maxmiize button, itf i want to maxmize a box then it need to maximize on the page,(Something like  browser window buttons)

Comment: Now I got what do you want. See this link [dialogr](http://carvalhar.com/componente/jQueryDialogr/index.html) that comes from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).
Can be I lot of code to get the style you need, but the function I think it's all right.